# Incrementing array elements in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I'm currently trying to make my way through Kernighan and Ritchie's book. I have a question about the code they use to introduce arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) /* What does this 'for' loop do? */

    {
        ndigit[i] = 0; 
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') /* Why are the numbers in quotes? */
        {
            ++ndigit[c - '0']; /* What does the "- '0'" part do? */

        }
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        {
            ++nwhite;
        }
        else
        {
            ++nother;
        }
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Comment: the questions are in the comments of this code example?

Comment: I think you need to go back to the chapter of the textbook that explains the `char` data type. A character in quotes is a `char` literal, and it's the numeric code used to represent that character.

Comment: K&R is pretty much self-contained. If you can't understand something, it's a sign that you have skipped something important.

Comment: Go back and read about what a `char` is. C is a very low-level language, the distinction between a char and and int is.... not much.

Comment: The `for` loop sets every element of the array to `0`. It does the same as this alternative definition `int ndigit[10] = { 0 };` would do.

Comment: I'll give you  hint of what is going on with arithmetic operators and character literals: https://repl.it/Iel9

Comment: @Barmar "A character in quotes is a"   _character constant_.  Only literals specified in C are _string literals_ and _compound literals_.

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to learn a language by reading it without having any idea of what it could mean. I don't think that looking into other's code is a bad idea to improve your knowledge, but I think -and I would suggest you to do so- that you should learn things from the start, which means for example follow a tutorial that will learn you the basics of this language and help you understand better how it works. This way, you won't have to ask for assistance all the time: indeed, if you don't understand what's in this code, then you will probably not understand a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question in the code comments:

`/* What does this 'for' loop do? */`

This for loop is iterating from 0 to 9 assigning each of the elements in `ndigit` the value 0.

`/* Why are the numbers in quotes? */`

The function `getchar()` gets one character from stdin, which is user input.
Text is a collection of ASCII values which can be referred to by individual characters, using a single quote `'a'`.
Even though `getchar()` is really returning a `char` value (1 byte) the actual return value is an `int` so it can return `-1` on error.

So this `char` value stored in an `int` is being checked to make sure it's something between the ASCII characters '0' and '9'. The ASCII value of '0' is 48 as a numeric value.

`/* What does the "- '0'" part do?`

Because '0' is the first ASCII numeral by subtracting this value from characters '0' to '9' it effectively is converting into the numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

1. *What does this 'for' loop do?* Set all elements of array ndigit to 0.
2. *Why are the numbers in quotes?* Because they are not numbers, but characters.
3. *What does the "- '0'" part do?* This converts digit characters to digits. This works because characters are ordered in ASCII standard - '0' char has a value of 48, '1' is 49, etc...

Comment: More importantly (only) the *digit* characters `'0'` to `'9'` must be ordered in the **C standard**. No matter what the encoding system is, having checked the character range, `c - '0'` will produce a number in the range `0` to `9` which is used to index the array.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to comment this code for you.
Remember that ndigit is an array of integers and initializing an array of integers means, often, set all of its values to zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) /* This loop initializes the ndigit array */

    {
        ndigit[i] = 0; 
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') /* c is a char, not an int */
        {
         ++ndigit[c - '0']; /*a difference between two chars numeric values*/

        }
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        {
            ++nwhite;
        }
        else
        {
            ++nother;
        }
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Comment: Better detail `/* c is a char, not an int */` --> In the loop, `c` is an `int` with a value in the range of `unsigned char`.

Comment: Explained much better than me, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your questions are the comments in the code:

What does this 'for' loop do?

The first loop clears out an array. In C all functions operating on strings uses the byte value of 0 to indicate end of string.

Why are the numbers in quotes?

Anything in single quotes indicates the ASCII value for the char in the quotes, so '0' is the ASCII value for 0 which is 48

What does the "- '0'" part do?

So that expression will subtract the ASCII value of an input from the ASCII value of '0' to get the numeric value. i.e. '0' - '0' will give 0, '1' - '0' give 1 etc.

Comment: Third para: the question has nothing to do with strings or string terminators. `ndigit[10]` is an `int` array anyway. More relevant is that local variables must be explicitly initialised.